# Sort and paginate a QuerySet in Django

Tags: django, python-3.5

Is there any way to sort and paginate a list in Django with Python 3.5.4? The only app that works for me in Python 3.5.4 is `webstack-django-sorting` **which only sorts**, and it does not work with the native Django pagination.

I tried with:

- linaro-django-pagination (which webstack-django-sorting recommends)
- django_filter
- django_pagination

In order to respond Arpit Solanki:

For example:[image] 
When I click this button for the first time I want to order the QuerySet of the products by Price ascendant, if I click it again I want to order QuerySet by Price descendant. This funtionality can does it `webstack-django-sorting` automatically, because this app creates the button and order the QuerySet when you click on it without write anything in the views.py

Comment: what is sort in your context? On based on which param you want to sort? is it a queryset ? There are builtin functions available to sort a list did you try any one of them?

Comment: I want to sort based on the attributes of the entity. For example: Price, Date of a Product. ´webstack-django-sorting´ does it automatically but I only can or sort with ´webstack-django-sorting´ or paginate with the native Django pagination but no both at the same time.

Comment: Do you know order_by and filter? Using those you can easily sort based on any attribute. Then you can convert it to list. No need to sort a list when you have a queryset

Comment: Yes I know it. I meant QuerySet not list, sorry. If I do it with filter and order_by I have to do it manually with JavaScript functions depending on whether I click once or twice... 
I would have to contemplate all the options while webstack-django-sorting makes it automatic...

Comment: So this is a javascript question of sorting a json like data structure. This does not have much to do with django

Comment: Clearly phrase your question that what is your exact requirement with some example. Your question is way too abstract.

Comment: I edited the question.